# Meta-analysis forest plot removing common effect model estimate

Tags: r, r-forestplot, metafor

I am performing a meta-analysis of proportions using metaprop function. I am looking at the prevalence of heart fibrosis in people living with HIV.

```
#mri$lgehivn <- number in people with HIV with fibrosis
#mri$lgehivn <- total number of peopl with HIV who have had CMR
lge.prop <-  metaprop(event = mri$lgehivn, 
                   n = mri$hivnmri,
                   subset = c(1:11, 13:16),
                   studlab = paper,
                   data = mri,
                   method = "Inverse"
                   sm = "PLOGIT", 
                   random = TRUE, 
                   hakn = FALSE,
                   pscale = 100,
                   digits = 1)
```

I am then passing this into a forest plot:

```
forest.meta(lge.prop, 
            rightcols=FALSE,
            leftcols=c("studlab", "event", "n", "effect", "ci"),
            leftlabs = c("Study", "Cases", "Total", "Prevalence", "95% C.I."),
            xlim= c(0,110),
            smlab = c("Prevalence of LGE (%)"),
            digits = 1,
            colgap.left = 1)
```

This then gives me the following forest plot:
[Forest plot of meta analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tQPo.png)

I am trying to remove the line that reports the "Common effect model" and only show the random effect model.
Does anyone know the code for this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if it is still relevant but I think that this was introduced with a newer version of the meta package.
When manually installing version 4.15-1, the common effect model was removed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the bellow code before making forest figure

```
lge.prop <-  metaprop(event = mri$lgehivn, 
               n = mri$hivnmri,
               subset = c(1:11, 13:16),
               studlab = paper,
               data = mri,
               method = "Inverse"
               sm = "PLOGIT", 
               random = TRUE, 
               hakn = FALSE,
               pscale = 100,
               digits = 1,
               common=F)
```

Answer (score 0):

set random=TRUE, common = FALSE.